# Kicking a user in Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I made this code to kick a user from the guild of a discord server

The bot console doesn't give me any errors, but this code doesn't work properly when I try to kick a user.
What I mean by this is that it doesn't kick the user, and it doesn't output anything in the channel.

I also checked the bots permissions, and updated these so this can't be the problem.

The version of discord.net is 1.0.2

```
    [Command("kick"), Alias("Kick"), Summary("Kicks a user from the server")]
    public async Task Kick(SocketGuildUser userAccount, string reason)
    {
        var user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
        var role = (user as IGuildUser).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Admin");
        if (!userAccount.Roles.Contains(role))
        {
            if (user.GuildPermissions.KickMembers)
            {
                await userAccount.KickAsync(reason);
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"The user `{userAccount}` has been kicked, for {reason}");
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("No permissions for kicking a user.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("This User can't be kicked, because the user has a admin role.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add to your post what "doesn't work properly" means? Is there any kind of output in the channel?

Comment: @Compufreak I updated it, but no there is no output in the channel

Comment: Hmmm this means it's either not called at all or fails somewhere in the first 10 lines. I am not into Discord.Net, but I'd recommend calling SendMessageAsync after each line so you can see how far it gets, so you can narrow down in which line the issue occures.

Comment: Done use 1.0.2 its way too old man. Just use 2.x. Its much more stable and causes no issues at all. And moreover nothing much has changed

Comment: @Rishav Okay, I'll try to update it to 2.x and see if that solved the problem

Comment: @Rishav I updated to 2.0 but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, instead of using the

```
async Task Kick(SocketGuildUser userAccount, string reason)
```

I needed to use

```
async Task Kick(IGuildUser userAccount, string reason)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Command("kick")]
[RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)]
public async Task KickAsync(IGuildUser user)
{

    var GuildUser = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id);

    if (!GuildUser.GuildPermissions.KickMembers)
    {
        await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
        await ReplyAsync(":warning: `No permissions to kick players`");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        await user.KickAsync();
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($":eye: `{user.Username} has been kicked from the server`");

        var guild = Context.Guild;
        var channel = guild.GetTextChannel(609086251978457098); //582790350620327952

        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

        builder.WithTitle("Logged Information")
            .AddField("User", $"{user.Mention}")
            .AddField("Moderator", $"{Context.User.Username}")
            .AddField("Other Information", "Can be invited back")
            .AddField("Command", $"``.kick {user.Username}``")
            .WithDescription($"This player has been kicked from {Context.Guild.Name} by {Context.User.Username}")
            .WithFooter($"{Context.User.Username}", Context.User.GetAvatarUrl())

            .WithCurrentTimestamp()
            .WithColor(new Color(54, 57, 62));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation too.